# Jordan block and commutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem:

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb F)$ Jordan block. Meaning, $A=J_n(\lambda), \space \lambda\in\mathbb F$. And let $B \in M_n(\mathbb F)$ matrix such that $AB=BA$. Prove that there is a polynom $p\in\mathbb F[t]$ such that $p(A)=B$.

I know that there is a formula for posting Jordan block in a polynom, but I do not know if it helps. Any suggestions? thanks for helpers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: here is a direct approach: you have $(A-\lambda I)B=B(A-\lambda I)$. Prove that $B$ is constant on the diagonals and upper-triangular. Now look at the formula you mentioned and do some interpolation.

Comment: could you open your explanation?

Comment: well, just look at the matrix elements of $(A-\lambda I)B$ and $(B-\lambda I)A$. If you have problems in general case, consider first matrices with sizes $2$ and $3$..